# In Smarty products with the same ID adding together

Tags: php, html, smarty

Do I have a chance in Smarty list items with the same ID (Product ID) together to count (add)?

```
{$order_value}
{$qty_value}
{$id_value}
{$title_value}
```

Instead of this:

```
Order: 004, Quantity: 3, Product ID: 001, Title: Fish
Order: 005, Quantity: 1, Product ID: 001, Title: Fish
```

something like this:

```
Quantity: 4, Product ID: 001, Title: Fish
```

Comment: This is much better done in the PHP application code, or better still in the database query. It's probably possible in smarty, using PHP array function modifiers or by building a complex array with `{assign}`, but will be far easier to accomplish and understand if you do it in your controller code.  Can you modify the code, or the original query?

Comment: is difficult. I had to write a new module. :-(

It would be better if would go right in the Smarty.